# How to add, delete and edit data in Stetho?

Tags: android, realm, stetho

I have an android app that stores data using Realm. I view the data using Stetho. But don't know how to edit the data directly from Stetho.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add the dependency to gradle:
`stetho-js-rhino`

Then, in chrome browser

- Go to `chrome://inspect/#devices`
- `Inspect` (make sure your device is connected properly)
- In the `resources` tab in the stetho console you will find `show drawer`
- Click in `Web SQL` on your database name in the leftside menu ...

Now you are able to display or alter the tabledata with the same commands as in sqlite.

For more information go to:

http://facebook.github.io/stetho/
 https://sqlite.org/docs.html

In case the dependency is missing you will get the following error:

[image: Stetho js-rhino requirement]

Comment: to add the rhino dependency, update build.gradle with: `implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-js-rhino:1.5.0'`

Comment: not working for editing.. am im doing something wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue as @BlueBot  - I can see DB contents, but have no idea how to execute queries. I type the query, press enter... and nothing happens. How do I execute it?

Comment: Oh, it's a Chrome bug: https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/634